PAST PASSIVE VOICE - Urgent Question That Confuses Me
I would sincerely appreciate your guidance with this particular question.
In the past passive voice, what is the difference in meaning between the following:
The window broke last night.
The window was broken last night.
I am confused in that I wonder if they mean the same thing. If not, then can you explain.
Thank you for your time!


"The window broke last night."

This sentence is in the active voice, meaning it describes an event that happened without specifying who or what caused it. The focus here is simply on the fact that the window broke. It suggests that the window might have shattered or cracked on its own, and there is no mention of anyone or anything causing it directly. The sentence leaves the cause of the event unknown or implied as something automatic or random.

Key point: It focuses on the event of the window breaking, without mentioning who or what was responsible.

"The window was broken last night."

This sentence is in the passive voice, meaning the action of breaking the window was caused by someone or something, but the sentence doesn’t explicitly state who or what. However, the sentence strongly implies that there was an external cause—whether it was a person, an animal, or another object. The window didn’t just break by itself; it was broken by something or someone, but the speaker either doesn’t know or chooses not to mention the cause.

Key point: This sentence emphasizes the result of an action (the window being broken) and suggests an external cause, even though the person or thing responsible is not mentioned.


In Summary:

"The window broke" suggests the window may have broken on its own, without assigning blame or specifying a cause. It feels more natural or accidental.
"The window was broken" suggests that someone or something caused the window to break. It implies an intentional or unintentional action by an outside force, but the doer is left out of the sentence.



In the past passive voice, what is the difference in meaning between the following:
1.The window broke last night.
2.The window was broken last night.

Please note that in your example
Sentence 1 is not active voice of Sentence 2.
Sentence 2 is the passive voice of:
"Someone broke the window.".
In your case, Sentence 1 suggests that the window broke on its own or due to natural calamity (storm, earthquake)
The reason for using a passive voice is given below: (there's no difference in meaning, only what we are emphasizing).
Ref. britishcouncil.org

We use the passive voice to change the focus of the sentence.
My bike was stolen. (passive – focus on my bike).
Someone stole my bike. (active – focus on someone).
We often use the passive:
when we prefer not to mention who or what does the action (for example, it's not known, it's obvious or we don't want to say).
so that we can start a sentence with the most important or most logical information


The only reason there's no (significant) difference in meaning is because a window can't break itself. If we say "the window broke," we understand that someone broke it. It's possible to find other nouns and verbs for which this is not true:

The chicken ate. A chicken ate something, perhaps a bug, or some chicken feed.
The chicken was eaten. Yikes! The chicken is no more! A hawk or hungry human got it.

Meanwhile, the past tense has no impact on any of this. "The window breaks/is broken" still has the same basic meaning, and "The chicken eats/is eaten" does not.
